# Launch virtualbox vm from url?

Tags: url, virtualbox

Is it possible to launch a virtualbox vm from a URL? 
For example, the HTML

```
<a href="apt://fortune/">install fortune</a>
```

will cause apt to download and install the fortune package (or at least find it and ask the user to confirm)

is there a way to do this with virtualbox vms? maybe

```
<a href="vbox://vm1/"> vm1 </a>
```

for example.

Edit: My OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: What OS are you wanting this to work on? Linux?

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit the question to note that :)

Answer (score 1):

Virtual box does not provide any url scheme handler. But you can create your own in windows just by adding a registry key. <sup>[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx)</sup>

Here is how a URL scheme `alert` could be created

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT 
     alert
          (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
          URL Protocol = ""
          DefaultIcon
               (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
          shell
               open
                    command
                         (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

After this `alert:Hello world` will be handled by `alert.exe` program.